# Convert python abbreviated month name to full name

Tags: python, datetime

How can I convert an abbreviated month anme e.g. `Apr` in python to the full name?

Comment: One piece of important information is missing: where does the abbreviation come from? That will impact whether or not the solution should take locale settings into account.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you insist on using `datetime` as per your tags, you can convert the short version of the month to a datetime object, then reformat it with the full name:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('apr','%b').strftime('%B')
```

Comment: Why isn't it able to parse Sept as September which is one of the standard abbreviations of September? Any other way to handle it through some library?

Comment: @AfsanAbdulaliGujarati the datetime library was written this way. See for instance strftime.org, which says `%b` is "_Month as locale’s abbreviated name_" and shows `'Sep'` specifically as an example. I suspect that the abbreviation depends on the locale, so in certain locales it may be possible that `'Sept'` is parsed. Anyway, some of the other answers use a manual mapping from long to short month name; these solutions can straightforwardly be used to define your own abbreviations (`'Sept'` included).

Comment: The only thing that worries me about the manual mapping is missing out on other possible abbreviations out there. I happened to somehow stumble upon the Sept thing.

Comment: @AfsanAbdulaliGujarati well the only automatically correct version is what comes with the locale. Any other choice is arbitrary, so you will have to you explicitly specify what you expect to parse yourself. You need to know your data anyway if it's in a non-standard format.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a method to use *calendar* library.

```
>>> import calendar
>>> calendar.month_name [list(calendar.month_abbr).index('Apr')]
'April'
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

```py
import calendar
months_dict = dict(zip(calendar.month_abbr[1:], calendar.month_name[1:]))
# {'Jan': 'January', 'Feb': 'February', 'Mar': 'March', 'Apr': 'April', 'May': 'May', 'Jun': 'June', 'Jul': 'July', 'Aug': 'August', 'Sep': 'September', 'Oct': 'October', 'Nov': 'November', 'Dec': 'December'}
```

Make sure you convert to proper cases based on your need.

Similarly, [calendar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) library also has `calendar.day_abbr` and `calendar.day_name`

Answer (score 2):

One quick and dirty way:

```
conversions = {"Apr": "April", "May": "May", "Dec": "December"}
date = "Apr"

if date in conversions:
    converted_date = conversions[date]
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple dictionary would work

eg

```
month_dict = {"jan" : "January", "feb" : "February" .... }
```

> > > month_dict["jan"]
> > >
> > > 'January'

Answer (score -1):

This is for mixed abbreviations and full month names, for example:

```
Dec 31, 2017
December 31, 2017
Aug 31, 2017
Feb 10, 2018
March 1, 2018
Jun 2, 2019
```

If you're doing it in a Pandas Dataframe with actual dates and you don't 
want `June` ending up mapped to `Junee`:

```
def replace_month_abrev(date_string):
    month_dict = {"Jan ": "January ",
              "Feb ": "February ",
              "Mar ": "March ",
              "Apr ": "April ",
              "May ": "May ",
              "Jun ": "June ",
              "Jul ": "July ",
              "Aug ": "August ",
              "Sep ": "September ",
              "Sept ": "September ",
              "Oct ": "October ",
              "Nov ": "November ",
              "Dec ": "December "}
    # find all dates with abrev
    abrev_found = filter(lambda abrev_month: abrev_month in date_string, month_dict.keys())
    # replace each date with its abbreviation
    for abrev in abrev_found:
        date_string = date_string.replace(abrev, month_dict[abrev])
    # return the modified string (or original if no states were found)
    return date_string

combined['deadline'].map(replace_month_abrev)
```